# Error en el entorno IDE java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola amigos este no es un problema de código pero es un problema de java en uno de sus IDE mas famoso, Netbeans, bueno me sale este error saben porque ?

si tengo instalado Java ¿ cual sera el motivo?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: instala el jdk http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: pero no vez que en la segunda imagen tengo instalado ya java?

Comment: es que descarge la version de netbeans para java EE sera por eso?

Comment: estas correcto es eso!!!

Comment: entonces cual sera mi error quiza tenga que configurar el IDE

Comment: ¿Seguro instalastes el JDK y no solo el JRE (Java Runtime)? No es lo mismo, y Netbeans necesita el JDK para funcionar. Para verificar esto, prueba la sentencia siguiente: `javac -version`, que es ligeramente distinto a la que probastes ya. Si no funciona, es que solo tienes el JRE instalado, pero no el JDK.